# !!expression for boolean

Tags: javascript

I was reading John Resig's **Secrets of JavaScript Ninja** and saw this code:

```
 function Ninja(){
   this.swung = false;

   // Should return true
   this.swingSword = function(){
     return !!this.swung;
   };
 }
```

I know `!!` is used to convert an expression into boolean. But my question is why does he use:

```
return !!this.swung;
```

Isn't that redundant because `swung` is already a boolean variable or am I missing something ?

BTW here is full relevant code just in case:

```
 function Ninja(){
   this.swung = false;

   // Should return true
   this.swingSword = function(){
     return !!this.swung;
   };
 }

 // Should return false, but will be overridden
 Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function(){
   return this.swung;
 };

 var ninja = new Ninja();
 assert( ninja.swingSword(), "Calling the instance method, not the prototype method."
)
```

Comment: Just a guess - I think it's for readability to let you know `swingSword` function returns boolean value.

Comment: "Should return true" is kind of a weird comment though... If it should return true, you can just `return true;`. Right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.swung` not a local variable, but a property of `Ninja`'s instances. So, the property can be modified by an external method.

To make sure that `swingSword` always return a boolean, an explicit conversion using `!!` is useful.

As for your code: I believe that it should be `!this.swung`, because `!!this.swung` returns `false` for `this.swung = false`:

```
this.swung = false;                                          // Defined in code
!!this.swung === !!false;                                    // See previous line
                 !!false === !true;                          // Boolean logic
                             !true === false;                // Boolean logic
                                       false === this.swung; // See first line
```

Comment: try ninja.swung = "foobar"; before the assert.

Comment: Ah, that could be the only legitimate reason. Thanks