# Manipulating array and finding path

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a angular application. My data is as follows :

```js
const data = 
  [ { id: 1212, name: 'julie', checked: true,  parentId:    1, parentChecked: false       } 
  , { id:   98, name: 'Rose',  checked: true,  parentId:   10, parentChecked: true        } 
  , { id:    2, name: 'Jamie', checked: true,  parentId: null, parentChecked: false, objectId: 10 }  
  , { id:   67, name: 'Kosy',  checked: false, parentId:  200, parentChecked: undefined       } 
  ]
```

1. if All the elements are checked then resultArray will be
   as `parentId === null`, `resultArray = [2]`  //
2. if for any element `checked` flag is `true` and `parentChecked` flag is also `true`, then I need to comapare
   `parentId` of that element with `objectId` of elements. till `parentId` become `null`.
   For example in above data, for `"Rose"` `checked` is `true`  and `parentChecked` is also `true`, then in this condition need to compare it's parentId with the element having same objectId which is element with `id: 2`.
   Need to do this till `parentId` becomes null. it's `parentId` is same as `ObjectId` of `Jamie`
   then In this case resultArray will contain `resultArray = [98]`
3. Now In case if for each and every element `checked` flag is `not true`, than in my result array I want to have id of all elements for which `checked` flag is `true` and `parentChecked` flag is `not true`.
   In this condition element with `parentId` `null` will not be considered as we have take it in above mentioned scenario.

For example, in data above, for some element's I have "checked" flag as true and `"parentChecked" flag is not true` and for some "checked" is false, in this case, result array will look as follows:

```
resultArray = [1212,67]  // as for id = 1212 and id =67 checked is true and parentChecked flag is false or undefined
// But in this condition we wont take element with parenId null in
// consideration as for each and every element "checked" flag is not true.
```

Once I get my resultArray, I want to pass each id of resultArray in findArray method in my stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8usqcc?file=index.js

Comment: i see only one object with `parentId: null`. why do you wnat two items as result?

Comment: In condition #2, would the result be [2] instead of [98] if `id:2` `parentChecked` was `true`? or would it be [2,98]?

Comment: no result will be 98 as I don't want to include element with parentId null because we have already considered it in first scneario. For the element with parentId null parentChecked will alway be false or undefined

Comment: no result will be 98 as I don't want to include element with parentId null because we have already considered it in first scneario. Also when parentChecked is true, then we are comparing element with id 98 is child of element with id 2. and I want to have only child in my result array. For the element with parentId null parentChecked will alway be false or undefined – Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
interface dataObj {
  id: number,
    name: string,
    checked: boolean,
    objectId ? : number,
    parentId ? : number,
    parentChecked: boolean
}

const data = [{
  id: 1212,
  name: 'julie',
  checked: true,
  parentId: 1,
  parentChecked: false
}, {
  id: 98,
  name: 'Rose',
  checked: true,
  parentId: 10,
  parentChecked: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jamie',
  checked: true,
  parentId: 200,
  parentChecked: true,
  objectId: 10
}, {
  id: 20,
  name: 'JamieParent',
  checked: true,
  parentId: null,
  parentChecked: false,
  objectId: 200
}, {
  id: 67,
  name: 'Kosy',
  checked: false,
  parentId: 200,
  parentChecked: undefined
}]

let resultArray_allTrueWithParentIdNull = []
let resultArray_someTrueWithParentIdNotNull = []
let resultArray_isCheckedAndParentChecked = []
let allTrue = true


// this function is SOLEY for condition 2
const recursiveCheckForParentValues = (el: dataObj, array: number[]) => {
  // first add this id to the array since it meets our condition 2
  array.push(el.id)
  // now find it's parent if there is one
  // it wil only find the parent
  let parent = data.filter((inel: dataObj) => inel.objectId == el.parentId)
  if (parent.length > 0) {
    parent = parent[0];
    // we found the parent, now test it for condition 2
    if (parent.checked && parent.parentChecked && parent.parentId) array.push(parent.id);
    // if our parent is ALSO a parent (has parentId), run it through this function again, and as many times as it takes until we hit NULL
    // we are sending array through as an argument, so it will keep accumulating IDs along the way
    if (parent.parentId) return recursiveCheckForParentValues(parent, array)
  }
  // return the final array
  return [...new Set(array)]; // removes duplicates
}

// loop through the array
data.forEach((el: dataObj) => {
  if (!el.checked) allTrue = false;
  else {
    if (!el.parentId) resultArray_allTrueWithParentIdNull.push(el.id);
    else if (el.parentChecked && el.checked) resultArray_isCheckedAndParentChecked = recursiveCheckForParentValues(el, resultArray_isCheckedAndParentChecked)
    else resultArray_someTrueWithParentIdNotNull.push(el.id)
  }
})


console.log(resultArray_allTrueWithParentIdNull);
console.log(resultArray_someTrueWithParentIdNotNull)
console.log(resultArray_isCheckedAndParentChecked)
```

Then to pass these values on to your `findInArray` method, you could do something like this

```
var output = { paths: [], found: false };
resultArray.forEach(id => findInArray(data, id, output));

console.log(output.found);
```

I also modified your stackblitz to accept an array of ids. Let me know if this works foryou:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mwzndk?file=index.js

Comment: how can I pass these id's to findArray method in my stackblitz so that my path is generated. Is there is any other good way to do it rather than using for each loop?

Comment: I updated my answer. Working on an alternative to forEach now...

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps. It's a modified version of your stackblitz to accept an array of ids rather than a single one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mwzndk?file=index.js

Comment: Hi, sorry I have got some updation in data and required condition. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: hi Kinglish let me know if you are updating your answer. I am waiting for your reply

Comment: no result will be 98 as I don't want to include element with parentId null because we have already considered it in first scneario. Also when parentChecked is true, then we are comparing element with id 98 is child of element with id 2. and I want to have only child in my result array. For the element with parentId null parentChecked will alway be false or undefine

Comment: are you updating your answer?

Comment: @Julie - I think I understand, and I revised my answer. In my answer, 3 different arrays are created. I am not sure which one you want to use as result array, but that should be easy for you to determine. Let me know if you have any issues. (I didnt update stackblitz, just this)

Comment: @Julie - forgot ot make my condition 2 function recursive. Just a moment...

Comment: Give me sometime, I am testing it and will update

Comment: okay let me know once you update your answer

Comment: is it possible to update your answer as one solution. As in my code I will be giving input array and I want to get output.

Comment: if we can do something if else and combine this code. Just a idea. is it possible to do that?

Comment: @Julie - I revised my answer, now that function is recursive, and I updated data to test it (you see now Julie has a parent). To answer your other question, unfortunately I have to go. I hope this code helps you along, please accept as the answer if it does. Cheers!

Comment: I will test it. Just a request, Could you please add detailed comments in your answer as I am finding it very hard to understand

Comment: @Julie - I will - but I have a question. You have 3 conditions. Are they in order of importance? (since you want a single resultArray in the end). Can we say: if condition 3 array has ids, use that. ELSE if condition 2 array has ids, use that. ELSE use condition 1 array  - ?

Comment: I updated with comments on the recursive function. I also modified it to make sure it checks all the way up the chain until it gets a parentId that is NULL.

Comment: Just one doubt in stackblitz it is working fine but in VS code it is saying like "propert checked does not exist on type any[]" and same for parentChecked and same for parent.id and same for parent.parentId. Ant idea?

Comment: Where can I see and  test that? Actually, that sounds like a separate question. Why not mark this as the answer, and post another question...

Comment: I am talking about your answer only

Comment: you can test that in you VS code if you have in your pc/laptop

Comment: @Julie - is this a typescript project?

Comment: @Juie - I can't test this, but I updated my answer. I created an interface for the data object that should accomodate your needs. I also typed all function arguments, which should take care of it. However without testing I don't know, maybe there are other variables to type.  It won't run in the snippet since the snippet JS is not Typescript aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for something like this:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1212,
  name: "julie",
  checked: true,
  parentId: 1,
}, {
  id: 98,
  name: "Rose",
  checked: false,
  parentId: 1,
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Jamie",
  checked: true,
  parentId: null,
}, {
  id: 67,
  name: "Kosy",
  parentId: 200,
  checked: true,
}];

const isAllChecked = data.every((element) => element.checked);
const result = data.filter((element) => {
  return isAllChecked ?
    element.parentId === null :
    element.checked && element.parentId !== null;
}).map((element) => element.id);

console.log('Result', result);
```

Comment: how can I pass these id's to findArray method in my stackblitz so that my path is generated. Is there is any other good way to do it rather than using for each loop?

Comment: your code is not running when I click on Run Code Snippet button. COuld you please have a look at it?

Comment: You can use your findInArray function inside the .map as well

Comment: Hi, sorry I have got some updation in data and required condition. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: no result will be 98 as I don't want to include element with parentId null because we have already considered it in first scneario. For the element with parentId null parentChecked will alway be false or undefined

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
const 
  data = 
    [ { id: 1212, name: 'julie', checked: true,  parentId: 1    } 
    , { id: 98,   name: 'Rose',  checked: false, parentId: 1    } 
    , { id: 2,    name: 'Jamie', checked: true,  parentId: null } 
    , { id: 67,   name: 'Kosy',  checked: true,  parentId: 200  } 
    ] 
, resultArray = data.filter(el=>el.checked && !!el.parentId).map(el=>el.id)
  ;
console.log( JSON.stringify(resultArray) )
```

if it helps... :

- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [!! expression-for-boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379478/expression-for-boolean)

Comment: how can I pass these id's to findArray method in my stackblitz so that my path is generated. Is there is any other good way to do it rather than using for each loop?

Comment: could you also please explain your solution by putting comments. i am finding it a bit hard to understand as I am newbie to JS

Comment: This doesn't satisfy all conditions the OP outlined

Comment: Hi, sorry I have got some updation in data and required condition. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @Julie, your updated question is very confusing for my language translator, then for myself too